# Trying to connect to bitcoin core on Google Compute Engine from an external IP, I was getting "couldn't connect to host error"

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I have having issue connecting my bitcoincore from an external ip address (Hostgator to be specific). The Bitcoin core is hosted on Google Compute Engine (Windows Sever 2012).

Here is what i have done

Bitcoin Core Config File

```
deprecatedrpc=1
dbcache=1000
txindex=1
server=1
rpcuser=myusername
rpcpassword=mypassword
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip = 192.185.35.200
```

N.B 192.185.35.200 is the dedicated server IP on Hostgator.
N.B 35.195.0.35 is the Ip for my VM on Google Compute Engine

I also disabled firewall totally on the windows machine

I specified compute engine firewall rule to allow access for TCP port 8332 and 8333

I contacted hostgator, they told me port 8332 is enabled for outgoing connections but not for incoming on shared server

https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ shows the 2 port as opened

But still, i can't get JSONRPC to talk to the bitcoincore. What i am getting is "Could't connect to host" .  When i make a call to with the EasyBitcoin Library.

```
<?php

include('easybitcoin.php');

$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('myusername','mypassword','35.195.0.35','8332');

$info = $bitcoin->getinfo();

print_r($info);


?>
```

What am i missing

Comment: try to allow all IP's instead of a specific IP , `rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: I did that already in the bitcoin config file

Comment: To be specific about the error, bitcoind was returning HTTP Unauthorized error

Comment: You mentioned in your question that bitcoind returning `Couldn't connect to host`, for the new error please edit the question.